# How to set reporting level for sonar preview analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using the sonar github plugin to generate preview analysis for pull request as described [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/github-pull-request-analysis-helps-fix-the-leak/). This works beautifully but because we are working with a lot of legacy code is it possible to:

- Set a minimum level for preview analysis (major and above)?
- Ignore existing existing issues and only report on new ones?

Comment: I am curious as well - nothing?

Comment: related question (unfortunately not answered either) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994996/setting-sonar-profile-together-with-sonar-preview-mode-on-maven-command-line