# Setting sonar profile together with sonar preview mode on maven command line

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to use a specific sonar profile with analysis mode preview for generating comments that go into our github pull requests.

The default quality profile for the project includes minor and info level rules which will cause hundreds of extra comments (and literally thousands of github notification emails). So it has to be a quality profile specific to this purpose.

Running the build like this:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.profile.java=PRComments -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
```

Fails with the following error:

```
sonar.profile was set to 'PRComments' but didn't match any profile for any language.
```

The PRComments quality profile exists and works perfectly if I don't specify the preview mode. And yes I know that -Dsonar.profile is deprecated and it makes me sad too.

For info I'm using the sonarqube github plugin http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin to push the comments into github - but the failure above appears even if I don't use this plugin.  Unfortunately the github plugin doesn't seem to have an option to skip adding comments for violations below a configurable severity level.

Is this possible or do I have to give up?

Comment: For info I'm using the sonarqube github plugin to push the comments into github but the failure appears even if I don't use it.- it doesn't have an option to silence

Comment: I do confirm that the SonarQube Github plugin should be used to cover this need as this is exactly the purpose of this plugin. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin

Comment: But the same applies using the plugin.  I can't filter comments for less serious levels and I can't specify a particular profile in preview mode

Comment: I am facing similar issue. We have a project on Sonar that we created a Legacy profile for it. The problem is that the GitHub plugin not supporting setting the profile and it is also not reading the profile from the server. So i with the plugin i am running analysis with Sonar Way proflle which makes a lot of noise

Comment: I think I'm just going against the sonar philosophy here.  I like having minor and info rules that give developers a subtle nudge by highlighting issues in their ide while they're working on new code - but I really don't care about fixing them in existing code.
I think sonar would work better if I drop all these completely.

Comment: related question (unfortunately not answered either) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994996/setting-sonar-profile-together-with-sonar-preview-mode-on-maven-command-line